# How can i find Braintree Sandbox Auth Key

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am working with braintree paypal checkout function, i found jquery code for that, i need to place Braintree Sandbox Auth Key in jquery variable, i created account in braintree, i tried all that code, but in jquery console log it says authrization failed, can anyone please help me where can i find that code ?
Here is my sameple code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
                <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.0/js/client.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.11.0/js/paypal-checkout.min.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

                <script>

                    var BRAINTREE_SANDBOX_AUTH = '38mqtdwp4nth5tbk';

                    // Render the PayPal button

                    paypal.Button.render({

                        // Pass in the Braintree SDK

                        braintree: braintree,

                        // Pass in your Braintree authorization key

                        client: {
                            sandbox: BRAINTREE_SANDBOX_AUTH,
                            production: '<insert production auth key>'
                        },

                        // Set your environment

                        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

                        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

                        payment: function(data, actions) {

                            // Make a call to create the payment

                            return actions.payment.create({
                                payment: {
                                    transactions: [
                                        {
                                            amount: { total: '1', currency: 'USD' }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer
                        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                            // Call your server with data.nonce to finalize the payment
                            console.log('Braintree nonce:', data.nonce);
                            // Get the payment and buyer details
                            return actions.payment.get().then(function(payment) {
                                console.log('Payment details:', payment);
                            });
                        }
                    }, '#paypal-button-container');
                </script>
            </body>
```

I need to place code in this variable `var BRAINTREE_SANDBOX_AUTH = '38mqtdwp4nth5tbk';` can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support@braintreepayments.com.</sup>

It looks like you are setting your `BRAINTREE_SANDBOX_AUTH` variable to a Merchant ID, rather than a [Client Token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/client-token). In order to initiate the Braintree checkout, you will need to generate, then pass in a `client_token`.

You generate the `client_token` [on your server](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/php#generate-a-client-token), then pass it into your [client-side call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/javascript/v3#initialize-components):  `braintree.client.create()`.

If successful, `braintree.client.create()` will return a client instance that you can use to create a PayPal checkout component with `braintree.paypalCheckout.create()`.

Within the [paypalCheckout component](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/javascript/v3#initialize-components), you can configure your PayPal button using `paypal.Button.render()`.